# Stress Tensor decomposition into Compression & Tensile forces

Tags: material-science, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

this might be a little more of an engineering question that physics but physics is my background so asking here...

I'm working on a project that does a finite element simulation of a mesh. I can output the stress tensor at each node, but I'm not so sure how to implement failure criteria.

If my material is brittle, say concrete, what's the best way to identify failure?

My current approach is to compute the von mises stress and compare against the compressive yield strength of the material, however this is completely ignoring the possibility that some portions of the mesh might be under tensile stresses for which the yield strength might be much lower.

Is it possible to resolve the stress tensor into tensile and compressive components?

Comment: Perhaps you should number your questions? When I googled some years ago I think I found a fracture criterion based on energy can't find it now though...

Comment: Right, I think I just followed the links on wikipedia, it was something about strain energy density. Isn't tensile and compressive just the sign of the stress in a certain direction (the one following the grains of the material)? Been a few years for me ...

Comment: Found something called distortional energy density criterion (DED) as well...

Comment: Maybe I'm not following, but why not apply a brittle failure criterion such as [Mohr-Coulomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%E2%80%93Coulomb_theory) (or whatever previous studies have tended to use for your material) and run the stress tensor at each point through this criterion?

Comment: Do you know how to resolve the stress tensor into its principal components?  One mode of failure is shear, as captured by the von Mises criterion.  But, if another mode of failure is tensile, you should look at the maximum (tensile) principal stress.